# bash, numeric prefix for emacs bindings?

Tags: bash, emacs, binding, prefix

Is it possible to use emacs bindings in bash shell with numeric arguments, for example in emacs C-u 5 C-d deletes five characters. Is there an equivalent way of doing the same in bash prompt?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Emacs is usually the default editing mode (`set -o emacs`).

From [Introduction to Line Editing](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/features_7.html#SEC42) and [Readine Arguments](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/features_7.html#SEC47):

The text *C-k* is read as 'Control-K' and describes the character produced when the Control key is depressed and the k key is struck.

The text *M-k* is read as 'Meta-K' and describes the character produced when the meta key (if you have one) is depressed, and the *k* key is struck. If you do not have a meta key, the identical keystroke can be generated by typing *ESC* first, and then typing *k*. Either process is known as **metafying** the *k* key.

The general way to pass numeric arguments to a command is to type meta digits before the command.  For example, to give the *C-d* command an argument of 10, you could type *M-1 0 C-d*.

**[Bash Emacs Editing Mode (readline) Cheat Sheet](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/plugins/wp-downloadMonitor/user_uploads/readline-emacs-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.pdf)**